# Create dynamic SQL query for search

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a SQL query to return data from a table and use condition in `where` but I where not have not have fixed condition, may be condition have 2 or 3 parameters, I want to avoid the `IF @PARAMETER >0`. I want to use a better and cleaner way to solve it.

This is my query :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllUsers(@p1 , @p2 , @p3 , @p4)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email
    FROM 
        [USERS]
    WHERE 
        id = @p4 AND firstName = @p2
END
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COALESCE` to make a parameter equal to the column it is being compared against when it is `NULL`, so that the test passes if you pass `NULL` for the parameter value. For example:

```
SELECT
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email
FROM [USERS]
WHERE id=COALESCE(@p4,id) AND firstName=COALESCE(@p2,firstName)
```

So when calling your procedure and wanting to fetch all `John` regardless of `id` you would use

```
GetAllUsers('somevalue' , 'John' , 'someothervalue' , NULL)
```

Comment: Building a dynamic query (to omit the tests for parameters which are `NULL`) would probably be faster on a really large table but this should be pretty good dependent on how well the query optimiser works (since it should be able to see `@p*` are constant and reduce the `COALESCE`s to a single value).

Comment: These kinds of queries (often called a "kitchen sink" query ) can suffer from parameter sniffing. https://blog.dbi-services.com/dynamic-filters-and-kitchen-sink-queries-dilemma/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for the link to that article, I've not seen any discussion about that form of optimising before. It seems that making a different query for each combination of parameters is probably the way to go, but I guess it probably needs testing almost on a system by system basis...

Comment: Correct. It may never suffer from parameter sniffing. Just be aware of it in case it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `NULL` to parameter which are not required and write your query like following.

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, email
FROM [USERS]
WHERE (
        @p4 IS NULL
        OR id = @p4
        )
    AND (
        @p2 IS NULL
        OR firstName = @p2
        )
```

Similarly you can build your query by adding other parameter.

**NOTE**: Syntax of your `CREATE PROCEDURE` is not correct, you need to mention the datatype of the parameters.

You can also use the default values to your parameters. Your final SP should look like following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllUsers (
     @p1 INT = NULL
    ,@p2 VARCHAR(100) = NULL
    ,@p3 VARCHAR(100) = NULL
    ,@p4 VARCHAR(100) = NULL
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT firstName
          ,lastName
          ,email
    FROM [USERS]
    WHERE (
            @p4 IS NULL
            OR id = @p4
            )
        AND (
            @p2 IS NULL
            OR firstName = @p2
            )
    --Add remaining conditions
END
```

Comment: i say in question , i dont like to use the if and same way . some body tell me to use json but i dont know how use with this way

Comment: Only other way I can think of is creating a dynamic query, that also requires if conditions to build the query. I don't suggest using a dynamic query for such scenario.